# Correlation between a continuous variable and a discrete quantitative, count variable

Tags: correlation, count-data, scales

I guess this is a classic statistical question but I can not find any clear answers (or at least one that I can understand) about my problem on the net.

I work in biology and I try to highlight a link between two variables. The first variable is a continuous quantitative variable (it is a measure of the intensity of a given signal, between 0 and 200). The second variable is a discrete quantitative variable (it is the number of stimulations that I do, between 0 and 4; so it is integer, count variable). For each stimulation, I have a number of measurements of my signal (between 4 and 15 measurements).

I have illustrated the kind of measurements that I obtain using a boxplot representation.

[image: my measurements]

I try to highlight the fact that the intensity of my (continuous) signal is correlated to my stimulation number (discrete). I do not think the Pearson or Spearman tests/coefficient are adequate in my case.

Could you tell me what is the statistical approach to follow?

Ideally, I would like to have a value, between -1 and 1, indicating if my variables are linked or not as well as a p-value to determine if they are significantly linked.

#### Edit

Thank you very much for your feedback and answers. To answer the different points, I went to the Department of Biostatistics and discussed with some folks there.

Many of them told be that I cannot use the Pearson or Spearman tests/coefficient. I went then to the conclusion that "the Pearson or Spearman tests/coefficient are adequate in my case.". From my understanding, I cannot use the Pearson test because of the fact that my data are not normally distributed.. The student gave me this paper to read: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22563845. I have no mathematical background at all but my understanding is that I can use the coefficient but non the p-value of the test.. In my case, I really need to have the p-value. It seems that I cannot have/use the test if my data are not normal, so I need to transform them... I have no idea by what to start with..

For the Spearman coefficient and its associated p-value, the software that I am using do not want to provide me a results because of the ties..

I had the feeling that many people at the Department have an idea, but they all have a different solution. I am trying to see in the literature, if someone had the exact same problem ?

Regarding the Binomial regression, will it provide me a coefficient and p-value?

Comment: Given a concern for whether there is a relationship here and whether you can claim significance (at conventional levels) I see no reason why you should not use Spearman correlation here. Indeed I see no reason why you should not use Pearson corelation here. You don't explain your reasoning to the contrary. There is some concern that correlation implies a linear model intensity $= a + b$ stimulation number, which is probably not the best model here: Poisson regression is likely to supply a better model. FWIW, I imagine on the evidence of your graph that significance is not an issue.

Comment: For your paper or dissertation fix the typo "mesurements" if you're presenting in English.

Comment: `I do not think the Pearson or Spearman tests/coefficient are adequate in my case.` Please explain why

Comment: Noting further that the measure is bounded I would revise my suggestion to some kind of binomial regression. The fact that variability is maximum at around 100 is consistent with that.

Comment: The dataset sounds small enough to post here should you wish detailed guidance. You're describing your response as continuous but bounded variables have characteristic relations between mean and variance. Consider that a mean of 0 or 200 must mean, in both cases, that all measurements are identical; hence variance must be 0 at the extremes. Conversely variability tends to be maximum for intermediate values. Hence binomial is likely to be roughly correct as a model, more so than normal.

Comment: Binomial regression will model the relationship, a better achievement statistically and scientifically than a correlation, here at most descriptive. Yes; P-values will be provided.

Answer (score -2):

This is a wrong statement, I do not have the answer for her problem but: You cannot use here the Pearson coefficient of correlation because the two variables do not follow each a normal distribution (one of them is a discrete variable). Moreover, she cannot use Spearman because there will be many cases with ties (equals value because of the 4 categories)...

---

Sorry, if I was too straightforward in my answer.

There is not need to rewrite hundreds of books and courses :). The is just a need to read carefully wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution.
As you will see, you cannot use Pearson coefficient and p-value if your data are not normal (at least the p-value computed by the traditional Student t-test)..

I can see the problem of Jess as we had the same problem, but we did not find the solution..

Comment: This is mostly incorrect as stated. 1. Suppose $x$ is uniformly distributed; $y = a + bx, b > 0$ therefore is also uniformly distributed. If your point of view is that lack of normality makes Pearson correlation (identically 1) invalid or inapplicable, you need to rewrite hundreds of books and courses. What you may be driving at is that inference levels for correlations requires some care, but we've had the bootstrap for nearly 40 years as I write. 2. Ties may make Spearman a little more problematic; they don't mean that you "cannot use" Spearman or even that you should not use it.

Comment: Also please [edit] your answer to specify what statement you are referring to.

Comment: As Nick said (and I agree), that is generally incorrect answer in both its statements.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.